# Can a foreign key in one table be non unique key attribute of the composite primary key of the second table?

Tags: sql, sqlite, foreign-keys

Here is **table1**:

```
 CREATE TABLE "table1" (
"date"  TEXT NOT NULL,
"dispenser" TEXT NOT NULL,
"start_reading" REAL NOT NULL,
"end_reading"   REAL,
"fuel_sold" REAL,
"amnt_earned"   REAL,
"profit"    REAL,
PRIMARY KEY("date","dispenser"),
);
```

Here is **table2**:

```
CREATE TABLE "discounts" (
"id"    INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT UNIQUE,
"date"  TEXT,
"name"  TEXT,
"discount"  REAL,
FOREIGN KEY("date") REFERENCES "daily_reports"("date")
);
```

When i try to insert data in **table2**  it gives a foreign key constraint error.

```
Insert into discounts(date,name,discount) values(@date,@name,@amount)
```

Comment: That FK is invalid - and shouldn't be able to create. A FK must reference a complete key.

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code, including smallest representative example input as code; desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. Give the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) For SQL that includes DBMS & DDL (including constraints & indexes) & input as code formatted as a table. PS You didn't run this code. Look at all compiler output. PS Read the manual & an introduction re FKs.

Comment: What is your 1 question? Why you got the error will be a faq. Your title is a faq. Before considering posting please read the manual & google any error message or many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular strings/names & site:stackoverflow.com & tags; read many answers. If you post a question, use one phrasing as title. Reflect your research. See [ask] & the voting arrow mouseover texts.

Answer (score 0):

No.

As the name suggests, a "foreign key" is a key of another table. And a key, by definition, is unique on the foreign table.